# Where is Xamarin Starter for Visual Studio 2013 Community?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin

Has Xamarin released their starter edition for Visual Studio 2013 Commmunity as described in their blog (http://blog.xamarin.com/microsoft-and-xamarin-expand-global-partnership)?

Answer (score 1):

If you read through the second point on there about the Community Edition it says: This will be available in the coming weeks.

We have double the size already, but community edition support will be coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot find it anymore but I read something that currently only Visual Studio 2015 is supported but that there will be 2013 support. I did not try it but you can give it a try. Go to [Xamarin Starter](http://xamarin.com/starter) and download it. It will be the same as the "trial version" but as I read on [this page](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11180/activating-the-starter-edition) it should be the starter edition as long as you don't use any features that are not included in the starter edition. Look at [the store](https://store.xamarin.com/) to see the differences between the different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xamarin has released both starter edition and plugin for Visual Studio 2013 Commmunity.

You could download Xamarin by the link below or from their site:

[xamarin.com/download](http://xamarin.com/download)